# Dynamically change width depending on value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, math

I have a div that is 250px and inside that div i have 3 children divs.

I want each of those 3 divs to scale depending on the value they have. So they scale up to 100% in the end.

I have this at the moment.

```
  <div className="spread">
    <div className="detractors" style={{width: 250 * this.state.analytics.spread.detractors / 100 + '%'}}>
      {this.state.analytics.spread.detractors}
    </div>
    <div className="passive" style={{width: 250 * this.state.analytics.spread.passives / 100 + '%'}}>
      {this.state.analytics.spread.passives}
    </div>
    <div className="promoters" style={{width: 250 * this.state.analytics.spread.promoters / 100 + '%'}}>
      {this.state.analytics.spread.promoters}
    </div>
  </div>
```

i'm trying to achieve this:

[image]

Comment: The width should be **either** a percent, or a value based on 250, but not both.  A percent doesn't depend on the width of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the width as a percent of the total or you can calculate a value dependent on the fixed width, but these are two separate things.  If you are calculating a percent then the width `250` should not be a factor.  The denominator is the total sum of the three.

```js
const RenderSpread = ({detractors, passives, promoters}) => {
  const sum = detractors + passives + promoters;
  return (
    <div className="spread">
      <div className="detractors" style={{ width: 100 * detractors / sum + '%'}}
      >
        {detractors}
      </div>
      <div className="passive" style={{ width: 100 * passives / sum + '%' }}>
        {passives}
      </div>
      <div className="promoters" style={{ width: 100 * promoters / sum + '%' }}
      >
        {promoters}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<RenderSpread detractors={235} passives={670} promoters={2119} />, document.body);
```

```css
.detractors {
    background: red;
}

.passive {
    background: yellow;
}

.promoters {
    background: green;
}

.spread {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    color: white;
    font-size: 60%;
    line-height: 300%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```